# How to create a column that equals to the product of previous 5 obsevations of another column in R dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

For example, I have the following column in dataframe:

```
Num
1
2
3
4
3
2
1
0
5
```

And I want to make it into something like this:

```
Num Prod
1 -
2 -
3 -
4 -
3 72
2 144
1 72
0 0
5 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various packages/functions that do such rolling operations.

One way with `zoo::rollapplyr`

```
df$Prod <- zoo::rollapplyr(df$Num, 5, prod, fill = NA)
df

#  Num Prod
#1   1   NA
#2   2   NA
#3   3   NA
#4   4   NA
#5   3   72
#6   2  144
#7   1   72
#8   0    0
#9   5    0
```

Comment: your solutions amaze me always.  Could you please share other packages' names useful for rolling functions.

Comment: On top of my head, there is `runner` and `RcppRoll` package which have rolling functions.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `roll_prod` from `RcppRoll`

```
library(RcppRoll)
df$Prod <- roll_prod(df$Num, 5, fill = NA, align = 'right')
df$Prod
#[1]  NA  NA  NA  NA  72 144  72   0   0
```